# Regular Expression on Python

Tags: python

I write the solution of my code on a file and I need to read it for another code. 
But there is one problem , in the file which saves the solution , the variables are like:

```
x[1][1]=3 x[1][2]=5 x[1][3]=9 x[2][1]=3 x[2][2]=5 x[2][3]=9
```

what I need is :

```
x[1][1]=3 x[2][1]=5 x[3][1]=9 x[1][2]=3 x[2][2]=5 x[3][2]=9
```

how can I flip the for loop to change the indexes to the other way? I learnt that I can  make regex on python but since I could not find a good example of it, I could not apply it. Can you give me an example for  how to do it ?
Thank you so much

Comment: show us the code that stores this and fix that ...

Answer (score 2):

Read it as normal, then transpose.

You can transpose like this :

```
     x = list(map(list, zip(*x)))
```

Transpose "flips" the indices in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Actually transposing the list per Christian Sloper's suggestion is probably the most principled thing to do, but if you truly want to use regex to transform the string `"list[x][y]"` into `"list[y][x]"`, that's very doable:

```
import re
input_string = "list[3][4], list[7][8]"
pattern = r"\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]"
repl = r"[\2][\1]"
re.sub(pattern, repl, input_string) #list[4][3], list[8][7]
```